# How to crop a images (mammograms without fixed width and height) to a fixed size with preservation on ROI on them

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, crop, bounding-box

Disclaimer for those who are not familiar with DDSM dataset but they think they know the answer to my problem.

The Digital Database for Screening Mammography is quite poorly prepared for task of analysis with Convnets.
[Distribution of image height / image width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKgtm.png)

Considering that many of images (mass and calcification) have up to 6 bounding boxes per image, there is a need of supervised croping to fixed size with preservation of those bounding boxes
[Count map of images without fixed shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jhx9.png)

As for [metadata](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=77456407204648847380) (that i have prepared myself) i have a strong set of information about bounding box whereabouts, their centroids and class of abnormality. I need to crop all of images to fixed size of 1628/1058 pixels (1.5/1 ratio).
My question is - Does anybody have an idea how to do that except for loop with random croping an fitting ROI (bounding boxes) to newly obtained image?

```
            cp_img = cv2.imread(cp_og_crops[j])[:, :, 0]
            res = cv2.matchTemplate(og_img, cp_img, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)
            mn, _, mnLoc, _ = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
            MPx, MPy = mnLoc
            trows, tcols = cp_img.shape[:2]
            x_min = MPx
            y_min = MPy
            x_max = MPx + tcols
            y_max = MPy + trows
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after 12 hour i have a final solution for those metadata.

If anyone is interested, here is early version of code:

```py
import os
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import gc


def NewSizeNewBoxes(new_images_folder, fixed_meta_data_name, new_df_name, target_width = 1058, target_height = 1628):
    gc.enable()
    try:
        os.makedirs(new_images_folder)
    except:
        print("Folder już istnieje")
    fixed_data = pd.read_csv(fixed_meta_data_name)
    gc.enable()
    cols = [col for col in fixed_data.columns]
    for i in tqdm(range(fixed_data.shape[0])):
        ab_type = fixed_data.loc[i,"abnormality1"]
        if ab_type != "normal":
            max_width = []
            min_width = []
            max_height = []
            min_height = []
            for xmax in ["x_max1", "x_max2", "x_max3", "x_max4", "x_max5", "x_max6"]:
                max_width.append(fixed_data.loc[i,xmax])
            for xmin in ["x_min1", "x_min2", "x_min3", "x_min4", "x_min5", "x_min6"]:
                min_width.append(fixed_data.loc[i,xmin])
            for ymax in ["y_max1", "y_max2", "y_max3", "y_max4", "y_max5", "y_max6"]:
                max_height.append(fixed_data.loc[i,ymax])
            for ymin in ["y_min1", "y_min2", "y_min3", "y_min4", "y_min5", "y_min6"]:
                min_height.append(fixed_data.loc[i,ymin])

            img_path = fixed_data.loc[i,"image_path"]
            img = cv2.imread(img_path)[:,:,0]
            scales = [1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3,3.25,3.5,3.75,4,4.25,4.5,4.75,5]
            scales_= []
            img_width = img.shape[1]
            img_height = img.shape[0]
            for idx in range(len(scales)):
                if int(img_width / scales[idx]) > target_width and int(img_height / scales[idx]) > target_height:
                    scales_.append(scales[idx])
            good_scale = scales_[-2]
            dim = (int(img.shape[1]/good_scale), int(img.shape[0]/good_scale))
            img_resized = cv2.resize(img,dim,interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
            img = img_resized
            img_width = img.shape[1]
            img_height = img.shape[0]
            for j in range(len(max_width)):
                if max_width[j] >= 0:
                    max_width[j] = int(max_width[j] / good_scale)
            for k in range(len(min_width)):
                if min_width[k] >= 0:
                    min_width[k] = int(min_width[k] / good_scale)
            for l in range(len(max_height)):
                if max_height[l] >= 0:
                    max_height[l] = int(max_height[l] / good_scale)
            for m in range(len(min_height)):
                if min_height[m] >= 0:
                    min_height[m] = int(min_height[m] / good_scale)
            max_w = np.nanmax(max_width)
            min_w = np.nanmin(min_width)
            max_h = np.nanmax(max_height)
            min_h = np.nanmin(min_height)

            distance_from_right_border = img_width - max_w
            distance_from_left_border = min_w
            distance_from_bottom_border = img_height - max_h
            distance_from_top_border = min_h
            ROI_width = max_w - min_w
            ROI_height = max_h - min_h
            pad_width = target_width - ROI_width
            pad_height = target_height - ROI_height
            if fixed_data.loc[i,"side"] == "LEFT":
                pad_right = int(max_w + distance_from_right_border)
                pad_left = int(min_w - (pad_width - distance_from_right_border))
                if distance_from_bottom_border < int(pad_height / 2):
                    pad_bottom = int(max_h + distance_from_bottom_border)
                    pad_top = int(min_h - (pad_height - distance_from_bottom_border))
                elif distance_from_top_border < int(pad_height / 2):
                    pad_top = int(min_h - distance_from_top_border)
                    pad_bottom = int(max_h + (pad_height - distance_from_top_border))
                else:
                    pad_bottom = int(max_h + (pad_height/2))
                    pad_top = int(min_h - (pad_height/2))
            else:
                pad_left = int(min_w - distance_from_left_border)
                pad_right = int(max_w + (target_width - ROI_width - distance_from_left_border))
                if distance_from_bottom_border < int(pad_height / 2):
                    pad_bottom = int(max_h + distance_from_bottom_border)
                    pad_top = int(min_h - (pad_height - distance_from_bottom_border))
                elif distance_from_top_border < int(pad_height / 2):
                    pad_top = int(min_h - distance_from_top_border)
                    pad_bottom = int(max_h + (pad_height - distance_from_top_border))
                else:
                    pad_bottom = int(max_h + (pad_height / 2))
                    pad_top = int(min_h - (pad_height / 2))

            new_img = img[pad_top:pad_bottom,pad_left:pad_right]
            filename_ = fixed_data.loc[i,cols[1]]
            filename_ = filename_.split("\\")[1]
            fixed_data.loc[i, cols[1]] = os.path.join(new_images_folder,filename_)
            fixed_data.loc[i,"img_height"] = new_img.shape[0]
            fixed_data.loc[i,"img_width"] = new_img.shape[1]
            fixed_data.loc[i,"downscaled"] = good_scale
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(new_images_folder,filename_),new_img)
            dx = pad_left
            dy = pad_top
            try:
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x_max1"] = max_width[0] - dx
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x_min1"] = min_width[0] - dx
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y_max1"] = max_height[0] - dy
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y_min1"] = min_height[0] - dy
                fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox1_height"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "y_max1"] - fixed_data.loc[i, "y_min1"]
                fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox1_width"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "x_max1"] - fixed_data.loc[i, "x_min1"]
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x1"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox1_width"] / 2
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y1"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox1_height"] / 2
            except:
                None
            try:
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x_max2"] = max_width[1] - dx
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x_min2"] = min_width[1] - dx
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y_max2"] = max_height[1] - dy
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y_min2"] = min_height[1] - dy
                fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox2_height"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "y_max2"] - fixed_data.loc[i, "y_min2"]
                fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox2_width"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "x_max2"] - fixed_data.loc[i, "x_min2"]
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x2"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox2_width"] / 2
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y2"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox2_height"] / 2
            except:
                None
            try:
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x_max3"] = max_width[2] - dx
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x_min3"] = min_width[2] - dx
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y_max3"] = max_height[2] - dy
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y_min3"] = min_height[2] - dy
                fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox3_height"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "y_max3"] - fixed_data.loc[i, "y_min3"]
                fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox3_width"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "x_max3"] - fixed_data.loc[i, "x_min3"]
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x3"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox3_width"] / 2
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y3"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox3_height"] / 2
            except:
                None
            try:
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x_max4"] = max_width[3] - dx
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x_min4"] = min_width[3] - dx
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y_max4"] = max_height[3] - dy
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y_min4"] = min_height[3] - dy
                fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox4_height"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "y_max4"] - fixed_data.loc[i, "y_min4"]
                fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox4_width"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "x_max4"] - fixed_data.loc[i, "x_min4"]
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x4"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox4_width"] / 2
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y4"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox4_height"] / 2
            except:
                None
            try:
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x_max5"] = max_width[4] - dx
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x_min5"] = min_width[4] - dx
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y_max5"] = max_height[4] - dy
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y_min5"] = min_height[4] - dy
                fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox5_height"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "y_max5"] - fixed_data.loc[i, "y_min5"]
                fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox5_width"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "x_max5"] - fixed_data.loc[i, "x_min5"]
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x5"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox5_width"] / 2
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y5"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox5_height"] / 2
            except:
                None
            try:
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x_max6"] = max_width[5] - dx
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x_min6"] = min_width[5] - dx
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y_max6"] = max_height[5] - dy
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y_min6"] = min_height[5] - dy
                fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox6_height"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "y_max6"] - fixed_data.loc[i, "y_min6"]
                fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox6_width"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "x_max6"] - fixed_data.loc[i, "x_min6"]
                fixed_data.loc[i, "x6"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox6_width"] / 2
                fixed_data.loc[i, "y6"] = fixed_data.loc[i, "bbox6_height"] / 2
            except:
                None
        else:
            img_path = fixed_data.loc[i, "image_path"]
            img = cv2.imread(img_path)[:, :, 0]
            scales = [1,1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5]
            scales_ = []
            img_width = img.shape[1]
            img_height = img.shape[0]
            for idx in range(len(scales)):
                if int(img_width / scales[idx]) > target_width and int(img_height / scales[idx]) > target_height:
                    scales_.append(scales[idx])
            good_scale = scales_[-2]
            dim = (int(img.shape[1] / good_scale), int(img.shape[0] / good_scale))
            img_resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
            img = img_resized
            img_width = img.shape[1]
            img_height = img.shape[0]
            if fixed_data.loc[i, "side"] == "LEFT":
                pad_right = img_width
                pad_left = img_width - target_width
                center = int(img_height / 2)
                pad_bottom = int(center + (target_height/2))
                pad_top = int(center - (target_height/2))
            else:
                pad_left = 0
                pad_right = target_width
                center = int(img_height / 2)
                pad_bottom = int(center + (target_height/2))
                pad_top = int(center - (target_height/2))

            new_img = img[pad_top:pad_bottom, pad_left:pad_right]
            filename_ = fixed_data.loc[i, cols[1]]
            filename_ = filename_.split("\\")[1]
            fixed_data.loc[i, cols[1]] = os.path.join(new_images_folder, filename_)
            fixed_data.loc[i, "img_height"] = new_img.shape[0]
            fixed_data.loc[i, "img_width"] = new_img.shape[1]
            fixed_data.loc[i, "downscaled"] = good_scale
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(new_images_folder, filename_), new_img)
        fixed_data.to_csv(path_or_buf=new_df_name, index=False)
```